# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when adding com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory:4.3.0 dependency

Tags: java, azure, gradle

When adding com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory:4.3.0 dependency to my build.gradle file I am getting this error:

```
Caused by:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'management.metrics-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opentelemetry/javaagent/instrumentation/internal/classloader/BootDelegationInstrumentation$Holder
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 150 more

        Caused by:
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/opentelemetry/javaagent/instrumentation/internal/classloader/BootDelegationInstrumentation$Holder
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
            at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:67)
            at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:110)
            at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.findCustomizerClass(Introspector.java:1125)
            at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getTargetBeanDescriptor(Introspector.java:1119)
            at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:445)
            at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:283)
            at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:427)
            at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:283)
            at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:225)
            at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.getBeanInfo(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:254)
            at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:279)
            at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:183)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:174)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:248)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1594)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1434)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
            ... 160 more

            Caused by:
            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.internal.classloader.BootDelegationInstrumentation$Holder
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
                ... 180 more
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of it? I tried to upgrade the version but it requires different spring boot version that I am using. I am using opentelemetry in version 1.19.0. Could not find solution to this.

Comment: the best way to avoid this kind of errors is to use the microsoft and spring bom to manage the dependencies versions for you, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/boms/azure-sdk-bom/README.md

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when there is version incompatibility between the `spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory` dependency and other dependencies in your project.

- To resolve this, check the compatibility of the versions of all the dependencies in your project.
- Include the package versions which are compatible to your spring-boot application.
- To avoid this error, you have to downgrade/upgrade your spring-boot version of your project.
- As mentioned in the [MSdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide?tabs=SpringCloudAzure4x#prerequisites), you need spring boot 2.5 or above versions.

I have created a simple spring-boot application (version 3.1.0) and used the dependency `com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory:4.3.0`:

**build.gradle:**

```java
plugins {  
id 'java'  
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'  
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'  
}  
  
group = 'com.example'  
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'  
sourceCompatibility = '17'  
  
dependencies {  
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'  
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory:4.3.0'  
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'  
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'  
}
```

***I am able to build and run the application successfully.***

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

[image]